# Can't compile haskell project: linking step fails

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, osx-mavericks

I'm having issues doing a cabal run on my project. This project used to run properly, and I'm not totally sure what change broke it. I think it is related to the issues between [GHC 7.6 and OSX Mavericks](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-September/110320.html) (I'm using [Darin Morrison's homebrew formulae here](https://github.com/darinmorrison/homebrew-haskell)). [**Edit:** to clarify, this was working at one point on Mavericks, so this hypothesis may not hold up.] The problem appears to be in the linking step:

```
In-place registering chorez-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'chorez' for chorez-0.1.0.0...
Linking dist/build/chorez/chorez ...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_chorezzzm0zi1zi0zi0_ChorezzziRequest_AddResponse_con_info", referenced from:
      _s5X4_info in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Commands.o)
  "_chorezzzm0zi1zi0zi0_ChorezzziRequest_ErrorResponse_static_info", referenced from:
      _chorezzzm0zi1zi0zi0_ChorezzziCommands_route1_closure in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Commands.o)
  "_chorezzzm0zi1zi0zi0_ChorezzziRequest_parseRequest_closure", referenced from:
      _r7eV_srt in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Server.o)
  "_chorezzzm0zi1zi0zi0_ChorezzziRequest_parseRequest_info", referenced from:
      _s7nh_info in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Server.o)
  "_chorezzzm0zi1zi0zi0_ChorezzziRequest_zdfToJSONResponse1_closure", referenced from:
      _r7eS_closure in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Server.o)
  "_chorezzzm0zi1zi0zi0_ChorezzziRequest_zdfToJSONResponse4_closure", referenced from:
      _s7ng_info in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Server.o)
      _r7eQ_closure in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Server.o)
      _r7eV_srt in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Server.o)
  "_chorezzzm0zi1zi0zi0_ChorezzziRequest_zdfToJSONResponse5_closure", referenced from:
      _s7ng_info in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Server.o)
      _r7eV_srt in libHSchorez-0.1.0.0.a(Server.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All of these symbols are from my own project (judging by the names). Most answers that I've seen about this have to do with a certain library not linking properly. I suspect some of these symbols are generated by `deriveToJSON` from [`Data.Aeson.TH`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html). I've reinstalled a couple of times with no resolution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's what finally fixed it. My cabal config was something like this:

```
library
  exposed-modules:
      My.Module1
    , My.Module3


executable my-executable
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:
      base >=4.6 && <4.7
    , chorez
```

Main.hs for the executable imports `My.Module3`. `My.Module3` imports the private `My.Module2`. Including `My.Module2` under `exposed-modules` fixed the issue. I figured this out because I realized that all the symbols that couldn't be found came from that module. `cabal repl` worked just fine (I tested the modules by hand and they all basically worked), but `cabal run` didn't. I feel like I should be able to use a library with private modules in an executable, but in this case I just forgot to add the new module to the list, and I have no reason to make any module private, so I'm up and running for now.

Comment: This works for me. I had a private extras module, And a test that imported only the public module.

Comment: This also worked for me, but I agree that there seems to be a deeper problem here. It doesn't make sense that you have to expose all modules that are used internally...

Comment: Thank you! I had the same error and I had accidentally forgot to include one of the modules in my build-depends. Adding it in my `exposed-modules` solved it.

Answer (score 9):

A bit late to the party, but what you want is to put your non-exposed modules in the `other-modules` section.

From the [Cabal User Guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#modules-included-in-the-package):

> #### Modules included in the package
>
> For a library, `cabal init` looks in the project directory for files that look like Haskell modules and adds all the modules to the `exposed-modules` field. For modules that do not form part of your package’s public interface, you can move those modules to the `other-modules` field. Either way, all modules in the library need to be listed.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall and reinstall - not GHC, but Xcode.  That resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Nope. I uninstalled XCode and tried again. Didn't work. I then tried to reinstall ghc and cabal-install again (just in case the freshly installed build tools would do a better job). I finally checked again just now, and that didn't work either.